# How can a team win a game (specifically, a Splatoon 3 battle) without communicating with each other?

Tags: game-theory

So, I've been getting into Nintendo's Splatoon 3 video game. In this game, there are various types of team-based battles and battle stages. It's a little bit like paintball with a variety of rules.

One of the characteristics of all battles is that there generally is no communication with other team members, as there is no in-game chatroom or anything like that. Therefore, it is difficult or impossible to coordinate with other members of one's team. The game does tell you a lot about the current state of the game: where your teammates are, what equipment they have, where your team drew "safe zones," where some of the opposing team is and what they're doing, etc.

Various strategies for winning these battles are published online. However, to my knowledge, none of these guides approach the battles from a strictly/primarily game theory perspective, which is what I am interested in (thus this question).

Comment: This does not formulate a problem that can be solved by reasoned mathematical argument.  In particular the key phrase "without communicating with each other" in the title is not defined in the body of your Question, though the second paragraph makes it sound like this is a natural circumstance of all the games that are played.  Readers here will have little idea whether you allow some pre-game conventions among team members, such as bidding conventions in bridge, or you are more concerned with tactics that do not rely on team cooperation.  Much would be needed to make any rigor possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very interesting, but you will need to provide more information to make this answer rigorous; specify the rules (are there any objectives? are there any more lucrative spots inside the map where more players are attracted to/get more score for coloring? - if so, where are they located?) , map size, color coverage from each weapon and more information that you'd think be useful.

ATM, for my understanding, you can approach this question like the optimization of the best opening to mid game in chess - where your objective is to conquer the middle as soon as possible, and then protect it:

> As you get better at chess, you'll start to learn that the most important area of the board is the centre - that is, the squares e4, d4, e5 and d5. Think of these squares as being like the high ground. Just as in real warfare, controlling the high ground in chess is often the key to victory...
> [link for some chess principles @ chessstrategyonline.com](https://www.chessstrategyonline.com/content/tutorials/how-to-start-a-game-of-chess-opening-principles)

Assuming you cant communicate with your fellow teammates before the match - you can rush to the middle and color it as fast as you can, meanwhile signaling "safe space" as much as you can; By doing so, **you are signaling your team** about the importance of the center.
At this point you'll want to see how the game unfolds.
If your teammates follow you and a battle for the middle with the opposing team is arising - you will want to watch for your teammates moves, if they are staying and protecting the middle, go and protect the most exposed edge from flanking - and if they are running/chasing down enemies from entering your half, stay and protect the middle.

I hope it was helpful :) have fun!